# Spreadsheet pivot table with ranking

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, ranking, google-sheets-formula

I want to add *ranking* column in my *pivot* table. I used rank formulas in calculated field but it just *#N/A*.

How to calculate ranking based on the value in pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have little choice but to extend the source data for your pivot table. Ungainly, but for want of any better offers so far I suggest three additional columns:

C2: `=sumif(A:A,A2,B:B)`
D2: `=rank(C2,C:C)`
E2: `=rank(rank(C2,C:C,1),unique(D:D))`

each copied down to suit.

Then add to **Values** in the pivot AVERAGE (of `E`).

I renamed that field and changed the Text colour in I5:

[image: Ranking in GS pivot table]